# How can I test a React Native component behaviour and props using Jest?

Tags: testing, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have successfully set up the Jest test environment in a React Native component that draws a `Button` (basically a combination of `Touchable` and `Text` components).

I can run snapshot tests like the following:

```
test('Renders', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Button>
      Button
    </Button>
  )
  const tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

However, I want to make a step further and start testing the `props` of the component (i.e., checking that the *Button* text is passed as `props.children` and I also want to test the `onPress` functionality, simulating the user tap and checking that a passed function is called.

How can I do this with a Jest + React Native environment?

PS: I'm currently running this code with `react-native ~> v0.34`, `jest ~> v15.1.1` and `jest-react-native ~> v15.0.0`.

Comment: Did you read the docs for React? https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content

Comment: Yes, I did. They don't provide enough information to write the test I want to.

Comment: There is a useful thread on Jest about this https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1411. 
You can invoke any props via component.props.runMe() and then regenerate the JSON to check against the snapshot